# How do I get avatar.variant(size: "200x200") on Rails 5 to work using aws on production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I can't get user.avatar.variant(resize: "200x200") to work while using a cloud provider in production because it uses my website path instead of aws.

```
<%= image_tag user.avatar.variant(resize: "200x200") %> 

# Current Output
<img src="https://mywebsite.com/rails/active_storage/representations/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBCdz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--3f8b21aebb9ca4fc9fe9043a1acc3e77e999319a/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdCam9MY21WemFYcGxTU0lLTVRCNE1UQUdPZ1pGVkE9PSIsImV4cCI6bnVsbCwicHVyIjoidmFyaWF0aW9uIn19--6b94a1495d331d40bee31fadf0e8dc9323a7e1bc/image.jpg">

# Should be
<img src="aws.com/img.jpg">
```

I need to user.avatar.service_url.split("?").first to get the right path for the img but when I do this, I can't use .variant() because that path is a string.

```
# this works but can't resize    
<%= image_tag user.avatar.service_url.split("?").first %>
```

Any idea how I overcome this.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you remove the `?`? it should just work with the query string, it's there on purpose. Do you have imagemagick installed so your app can resize images?

Comment: I just updated the body, sorry about that. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: You could try `user.avatar.variant(resize: "200x200").processed.service_url` https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Variant.html but I think you have something wrong, doing that split doesn't looks right. I haven't use activestorage with aws so I can't tell you exactly how to use that, but you shouldn't need to modify the src by hand.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I posted an answer I got from gorails.com in case you were interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this answer from Chris Oliver form gorails.com:

"ActiveStorage URLs always go through your Rails app. That's how they generate the resize 200x200 on the fly without precomputing it. That's the primary downside to using ActiveStorage right now.

In a future version of Rails, they will have an option to use direct urls to AWS, but you can't do that right now.

If you want this feature today, you'd be better off using Shrine for file uploads."

I think this was useful and that's why I decided to share it here.